# C++ function parameter defined by children

Tags: c++, function, inheritance

I have an entity class that handles the selection of entities. In this class I have a vector of functions that is passed to the UI to be rendered into a drop down menu. I want to be able to create functions in my classes that inherit entity but pass those functions from entity to the UI. Any ideas on how I would do this?

What have I done?

I added a protected vector to entity:

```
std::vector<void (*)()> dropDownFunctions;
```

A function to UI:

```
void renderDropDown(std::vector<void(*)()> dropDownFunctions);
```

This is that function:

```
private:
    void calculateFOV();
```

And then tried to modify the vector in a class which inherited entity:

```
dropDownFunctions.push_back(&PlayableCharacter::calculateFOV);
```

I get the error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=void (*)(), _Alloc=std::allocator<void (*)()>]" matches the argument list
```

Comment: What have your done? Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Code says more than a thousand pictures. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: I have added my attempt

Comment: What the type of calculateFOV?

Comment: Added that now to the question.

Comment: Note that pointer to member functions are *not* the same as pointers to non-member function. Read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calculateFOV` is a nonstatic member function, so it has an implicit `this` parameter. Taking its address as `&PlayableCharacter::calculateFOV` yields type `void (PlayableCharacter::*)()`, a *pointer-to-member-function* or PTMF, which isn't compatible with `void(*)()`.

Assuming `PlayableCharacter` is derived from `Entity`, you might try:

```
typedef void (Entity::* DropDownFn)();
std::vector< DropDownFn > dropDownFunctions;
```

and then,

```
dropDownFunctions.push_back
                  ( static_cast< DropDownFn >( &PlayableCharacter::calculateFOV ) );
```

Comment: Am I only changing `std::vector<void (Entity::*)()  dropDownFunctions>` or is there something else? The same error occurs with or without the chage:  `argument types are: (void (PlayableCharacter::*)())` `object type is: std::vector<void(Entity::*)(), std::allocator<void(Entity::*)()>`

Comment: @genfy Sorry, that conversion needs to be explicit, i.e. `static_cast`. It's only implicit going from base to derived, which often seems backward.